# Trigger to changelog. How to improve?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am creating a trigger to enable changelog from any of those tables that are updated.
Some important points:

1. I have to create a trigger for each table that will be updated
2. I have one generic table to store all the changes:

`CREATE TABLE salesforce.slf_log_update(
    log_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    table_update VARCHAR(200) not null,
    update_timestamp timestamp DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
    field_updated varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    field_old_value TEXT,
    original_table_row_id INT NOT NULL
  )`

3. I have to create an specific query to select all the values that can be updated, an example, guess that I have a table where I can update two fields:

`SELECT 'tableA' as table_name,'field1_tableA' as field,cast(field1_tableA as varchar), datatype(), id_tableA  from tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT 'tableA' as table_name,'field25_tableA'as field,cast(field25_tableA as varchar),id_tableA from tableA`

The main problems that I see are:

- How to log any change on the table without doing a large query and keeping the simple log table created to store old values?
- I would like to add the connected user that make the updated. Is it possible?

Comment: [Here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger) is example of simple audit trigger. It will store session user, old row and new one. You can expend on it by only showing diff between data and/or store it as json for easy searching. [Here](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger) is more advanced audit system, also [featured](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) on postgres wiki.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński thank you Lukasz! I found very interesting this.